# force SQLite view column type affinity

Tags: view, datatypes, sqlite, cast

Using SQLite 3, I have some view columns which are defined with an expression, and so have no type affinity. Is it possible to define them in a way that forces them to have a certain type affinity?

e.g. if I have a tables `t1`, `t2` and a view definition

`create view v as select coalesce(t1.c1, t2.c1) c1 from t1, t2 where X;`

is there some way of giving `v1.c1` a type affinity? I've tried casting it

`select cast(coalesce(t1.c1, t2.c1) as INTEGER) c1`

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: SQLite uses affinity when storing data into columns. Views do not store data. What is your desired effect of forcing an affinity onto a view's column?

Comment: It's for database modelling and comparing schemas. It seems the closest thing to working out the type of the column

Comment: In SQLite, a view's columns do not have types. The values themselves have types, and there can be different types in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT CAST(COALESCE(CAST(t1.c1 AS INTEGER), CAST(t2.c1 AS INTEGER)) AS INTEGER) AS c1
FROM t1, t2 WHERE X;
```

n this case, both t1.c1 and t2.c1 are individually cast to INTEGER before being used in the COALESCE function. This ensures that the result of COALESCE will have INTEGER type affinity.

Please note that if the data in t1.c1 or t2.c1 cannot be cast to INTEGER, the COALESCE function will return NULL for that row. Therefore, you should make sure that the casting is appropriate for your data to avoid unexpected results.